# Using factoring to solve problems

Tags: linear-algebra

Each edge of one cube is 1 cm longer than each edge of another cube.The volumes of the cubes differ by 37 cm^3.Find the lengths of the edges of the cube.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! Please share your insights on the question with us so we can know how to help you best.

Comment: Where is your problem is it working out what equation you have to solve or solving the resultant quadratic equation?

Answer (score 1):

Let the smaller cube have side length $x$ and the larger cube have side length $x+1$ both in cm.

Now the formula you need to solve is:

$(x+1)^3 - x^3  = 37$

$(x+1)^3 - x^3  = (x^3 + 3x^2 +3x +1) - x^3 = 3x^2 + 3x+1= 37$

Solve for $x$

---

The OP has already got the correct answer but for compleatness

$3x^2 + 3x +1 = 37 \Rightarrow 3x^2+3x-36 = 0 \Rightarrow x^2+x-12 = 0$

There are several ways to solve for $x$. The quadratic formula, completing the square or factorising.  As the question asks about factorising.

consider $(x+a)(x-b)= x^2 + (a-b)x - ab$ we know $a-b = 1$ and $ab = 12$ so we can see $a=4$ and $b = 3$ is a solution.

We now have $(x+4)(x-3) = 0$ so $x=-4$ is a solution but does not match the real world, since we can't have a cube with negative side length. $x=3$ is also a solution and makes sense in the real world.

So the smaller cube has sides 3cm and the larger one sides 4cm.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the length of each edge of the original cube. Then $x + 1$ is the length of each edge of the new cube. The volume of the first cube is $x^3$. The volume of the second cube is $(x + 1)^3$. We know that the difference in volume is $37$, so $(x+1)^3 - x^3 = 37$. Now solve this for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$V_1=x^3$

$V_2={(x+1)}^3$

Given,

$V_2-V_1=37$

so, $x^3+1+3x(1+x)-x^3=37$

Or,  $3x^2+3x+1-37=0$

Or,  $x^2+x-12=0$

Or, $x^2+4x-3x-12=0$

Or, $x=3$ is the side on one of the cube.